# When I installed Ubuntu 13.10 my ethernet is not connecting

Tags: ethernet

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a new computer I put together however I am unable to get my Ethernet to work. What happens is my computer will go through phases of searching for a network and then occasionally pop a red box that says you are disconnected from the network.

here are the results of my `ifconfig`:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:58:b2:47  
          inet6 addr: fe80::76d4:35ff:fe58:b247/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:1034 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:53473 (53.4 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6272 (6.2 KB)  TX bytes:6272 (6.2 KB)
```

any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

after looking over my config I appear to have an ipv6 address. and I know for a fact that this particular network isn't configured to hand out ipv6 addresses (its a private home network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue I had was that I was using a realtek ethernet card which ubuntu has an issue with.

the directions I found here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489

they ALMOST worked. Others may have better luck with them.

In the end I just sprung for a usb to ethernet adapter that was compatible with my linux kernal and everything worked well.